# Pinescript - Series float used when fun_arg[] expected

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I am trying to convert Williams Percent Range values to the positive domain using the attached scripts. It does need a bit of tweaking, however when attempting to pass a float array as a parameter to the custom function the following error is generated:

**Cannot call 'array.size' with argument 'id'='duplicateArray'. An argument of 'series float' type was used but a 'fun_arg[]' is expected.**

I understand what it means. However I do not know how to fix it.

```
Code:

//@version=5
indicator("Williams Percent Range Average", shorttitle="Williams %R", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

// Williams Settings

williamsGroup = "=== WILLIAMS ==="
lengthWilliams1 = input(title="Length", defval=13,group = williamsGroup)
lengthWilliams2 = input(title="Length", defval=21,group = williamsGroup)
lengthWilliams3 = input(title="Length", defval=34,group = williamsGroup)

lengthWilliamsAverage = math.round((lengthWilliams1 + lengthWilliams2 + lengthWilliams3) / 3)
srcWilliams = input(close, "Williams Source")

_pr(length) =>
    max = ta.highest(length)
    min = ta.lowest(length)
    100 * (srcWilliams - max) / (max - min)
percentR1 = _pr(lengthWilliams1)
percentR2 = _pr(lengthWilliams2)
percentR3 = _pr(lengthWilliams3)
percentR4 = _pr(lengthWilliamsAverage)

convertWilliams(williamsCalculations) =>
    multiplier = 0.0625
    duplicateArray = williamsCalculations
    size = array.size(duplicateArray)
    modifiedWilliamsValues = array.new_float(size) 
    for i = 0 to size - 1
        n = williamsCalculations[i]
        diff_n = n + 80
        n_multi = diff_n * multiplier 
        new_n = (n / (-4+n_multi)) + 20
        array.insert(modifiedWilliamsValues,i,new_n)
    modifiedWilliamsValues

modifiedR1 = convertWilliams(percentR1)
```

Additionally I have never had to return a value from a custom function before. Could anyone tell me how to return the modified array using an equivalent of a return statement as the other error I get is:

**The end value of the "for" loop must be a number.**

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @vitruvius Hi, that should be a minimal reproducible example

Comment: That code does not compile and if I fix the issue, I don't see the error you mentioned.

Comment: Yea, it doesn't compile but that's because of the errors I get. How did you go about fixing it? So I pasted the full code for simplicity as I may be missing something you are seeing. However from the original version, the only difference is the version number and the additional input variables. Which only one was required.

Comment: Why are you using `array.size()`? `williamsCalculations` is not an array.

Comment: OMG, I see that now. For some reason I had the idea that the percentR function created an array. See the issue now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `convertWilliams()` like below:

```
modifiedR1 = convertWilliams(percentR1)
```

And `percentR1` is defined as `percentR1 = _pr(lengthWilliams1)`.

`_pr` returns `series float` so `percentR1` is `series float`.

Then you pass this to `convertWilliams()` and in that function you call `array.size()` on it which is why you are getting both errors.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it now. Just need to correct the formula now